# What is a body's momentum really equal to?

Tags: special-relativity

I know a body's momentum is equal to the product of its velocity and mass.  But what kind of mass?  Relativistic mass or rest mass?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The modern answer

> I know a body's momentum is equal to the product of its velocity and mass.

No, it's not. At least, not in general. $p=mv$ is an approximate formula that works well for massive particles or particle-like objects traveling at slow speeds. But for fast-moving objects, or massless objects, or things that don't even count as objects (I'm thinking of waves), momentum will have a different formula. For example, the momentum of an object moving at relativistic speed is
$$p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}$$
or the momentum of a photon is
$$p = \frac{h}{\lambda}= \frac{hf}{c}=\frac{E}{c}$$

Underlying this answer is the idea that mass is just mass. It's an intrinsic property of an object, more or less; in particular, an object's mass does not depend on how fast it's moving.

## The outdated answer

In the old days, one would say that momentum could be expressed as the product of relativistic mass and velocity, since
$$m_\text{rel} = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me. I was going completely insane trying to figure it out myself.  I'm afraid I'm ignorant of how to calculate the momentum of a light particle, but I'll research it.

Comment: One slight correction- I believe the momentum of a photon is hf/c, and its energy is hf.

Comment: The "outdated" answer isn't really outdated, it's just a little confusing. People still use this terminology. It's like saying inches are an "outdated" measurement unit...

Comment: @hft Most people who do relativity for their job dropped the relativistic mass and associated framing decades ago. Outdated is not much of an overstatement. It is true that there is some professional resistance to this change so I won't be adamant about the point, but I'd dearly like to sit every high-school science teacher in the US down and tell them to just ***stop*** already. It only confuses students as we see here.

Comment: Most people don't "do relativity" for their job... Physicists who "do relativity" are often working with "very high" energies where the so-called relativistic mass is very different from the rest mass. But in engineering-related fields, e.g., electron microscopy, the relativistic mass is still considered a useful concept. It's not just moron high school teachers who use this term. Admittedly, I also think the concept of *relativistic mass* is dumb and confusing, but I don't think it is outdated. I.e, we are in agreement about the dumbness of the term, just not its outdatedness.

Comment: I'm intentionally calling it outdated even though I know some people still use it - the implication is partly that it _should_ be outdated, not that nobody uses it.

Comment: @hft, but inches *are* an outdated measurement unit.

Comment: @jwg feels like we're on a semantic treadmill here, but in general usage 'outdated' can mean 'no longer used or useful'/'discarded'/'old-fashioned', so inches are *not* outdated in the first two of those senses and *are* outdated in the last sense. ... in any case, DavidZ is of the prescriptivist bent, so it's largely moot.

Answer (score 2):

The equation by David Z can only be applied for particles having mass not for photons or other massless particles.

The general equation is 
$$E^2-p^2=m^2,$$
where $E$, $p$ and $m$ are energy, momentum and mass of the particle resp.

And this mass is rest mass, there is nothing like relativistic mass in modern books.

Answer (score -1):

Relativistic momentum  is given by calculating Newtonian momentum, but instead of using mass, we use relativistic mass. Therefore, starting with

$p = m_0v$

To become correct, we use relativistic mass

$p = \dfrac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}v$

Or, in a more attractive form

$p = \dfrac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Comment: Note that relativistic mass is an outdated concept.

Comment: Note that it is not "outdated", it is just confusing. It is only "outdated" among academic physics students.

Comment: Again, outdated in the opinion of most professional users of relativity.

Comment: ...professional users of relativity in the context of high energy physics. That's a small clique... Not every one is so, um, civilized.